# Why it is not using the full key?

Tags: mysql

Here's my query and the explain output.

```
explain select * from ENSEMBL_DERIVED where 
SEQ_REGION_ID=27523 AND SEQ_REGION_START >= 12595527 AND SEQ_REGION_END <= 43811979
--------------

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ENSEMBL_DERIVED
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2004
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here's the table:

```
describe ENSEMBL_DERIVED
--------------

+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SEQ_REGION_ID     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| SEQ_REGION_START  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| SEQ_REGION_END    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| SEQ_REGION_STRAND | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| STABLE_ID         | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DISPLAY_LABEL     | varchar(128)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The **key_len** field in the explain statement indicates that only 2 out of 3 columns of the primary key are being used. Why is this? Is it a symptom of having >= and <= operators on two different columns?

Is there a way to optimize the query + table? I think, "using where" on 2004 rows may not be ideal.

Comment: can you also provide:
SHOW CREATE TABLE ENSEMBL_DERIVED;
please

Comment: Is this query running slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your query, only the first two columns in that index can be used for a "range scan". The predicate on the third column can't be satisfied with that same range scan. (There's no way for the engine to reduce the number of rows that need to be checked.)  The check of the predicate on the third column will be performed on every row that is matched by the range scan.

"`Using where`" is what we'd expect in the EXPLAIN output. Did you expect to see something different?

I don't see any way to optimize the query, unless we have some domain knowledge which would allow us to add some additional predicate. Since the query is returning all columns on the table, the primary key is already a covering index. (Is this InnoDB or MyISAM?)

If the table is fragmented (a lot of inserts, updates and deletes), then an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` may reduce the number of blocks that need to be checked, but that isn't likely to make much of a difference.